# Angular httpClient headers

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

Below is my HTTP post request to get the auth token, the headers are not getting set, in chrome I don't see the headers under request headers.

[image]

What I also observed is,  if I add only the content-type header I can see the header and body being sent in the request, if I add authorization header then no header or body being sent in the request and I see 
Response to preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401. error on console.

I also tried enabling "CORS" still the same issue.

have tried all the commented options.

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', 'authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa("infoarchive.custom:mysecret") });

//headers  = headers.append("content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
//headers  = headers.append("authorization","Basic " + btoa("infoarchive.custom:mysecret"));
//headers = headers.set("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization")
//headers = headers.set(Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
//headers = headers.set('Authorization', 'Basic aW5mb2FyY2hpdmUuY3VzdG9tOm15c2VjcmV0');      
console.log(headers)
const body = JSON.stringify({
    client_id: 'infoarchive.custom',
    username: userName,
    password: password,
    grant_type: 'password',
    scope: 'search'
});
return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/oauth/token', body, { headers: headers })
    .map(
    (response: Response) => {
        const data = response.json();
        console.log("data:" + data)
        //  this.saveJwt(data.json().id_token);             
    }
    )
    .catch(
    (error: Response) => {
        console.log(error.status)
        return Observable.throw('Something went wrong');
    }
    );
```

Comment: Try to use `headers.append` instead of `headers.set`

Comment: @CommercialSuicide I did try with headers.append, you can see them commented, still couldn't get it working

Comment: Sorry, I just missed that

Comment: Regarding CORS, as far as I can tell from my experience I only have this issue while in development mode and i have a chrome extension installed called CORS once you turn on the setting of this extension then you will not see the CORS error

Comment: Any luck on this, as I'm getting exactly the same as you.  It's like it just ignores the headers.  One thing that I noticed was that my "set" headers were appearing in a `lazyUpdate` property in HttpHeaders, and not in the main list?

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is use [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) for this purpose and once this is configured it will automatically add information to your header for every http request and you will not have to manually add headers for every http request.

Following is an example of how I am getting a **user** object from the storage and using its `authentication_token` and sending it as a part of a header.

I hope this helps.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import { Storage } from "@ionic/storage";
import "rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap";

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptorProvider implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private storage: Storage) {
    console.log("Hello AuthInterceptorProvider Provider");
  }

  intercept( request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return this.getUser().mergeMap(user => {
      if (user) {
        // clone and modify the request
        request = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${user.authentication_token}`
          }
        });
      }

      return next.handle(request);
    });
  }

  getUser(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.get("user"));
  }
}
```

I will also recommend you to read [this](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8) article as this will give you more insight on this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I have setup my `http.service.ts` with `HttpClient`. This works flawlessly for me and I can see my headers being set accordingly.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { RequestOptions } from '../models/http.models';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
  domain: string = 'https://example-production.systems/';
  options: RequestOptions = {
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'X-CSRFToken': 'example-token' }),
  };

  constructor(
    public httpClient: HttpClient,
  ) {}

  post = (path: string, payload: any, query?: string): Observable<any> =>
    this.httpClient.post(`${this.domain}/${path}/${query}`, payload, this.options)
}
```

If you're curios - my `RequestOptions` interface looks like this:

```
export interface RequestOptions {
  headers: HttpHeaders;
  withCredentials: boolean;
}
```

I built this interface off of the list of accepted HTTPClient options can be found on the various HTTPClient `client.d.ts` methods. For example - accepted `.post()` options are as follows:

```
post(url: string, body: any | null, options?: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {
        [header: string]: string | string[];
    };
    observe?: 'body';
    params?: HttpParams | {
        [param: string]: string | string[];
    };
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType?: 'json';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}): Observable<Object>;
```