# How to add custom headers to HTTP request Angular5?

Tags: angular5, angular-httpclient

How can I add a custom header to http request using angular5? 
I have tried something like this.

```
        import {Headers} from 'angular2/http';
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append(headerName, value);

        // HTTP POST using these headers
         this.http.post(url, data, {
         headers: headers
          })
      // do something with the response
```

Comment: May solve your problem:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464108/angular-set-headers-for-every-request

Comment: I will check this. Thanks :D

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49298431/angular-httpclient-headers

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below example for Custom header:

```
import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';


@Injectable()
export class AbcService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  search = (query) => {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Api-User-Agent', 'Example/1.0');
    let apiUrl: string = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.phpgsrsearch='+query;

return this.http
        .get(apiUrl, headers)
        .map(response => response.json());
  }
}
```